# reading value from memory for pointer location

Tags: c#, pointers

I need to get the value from memory location 0 to 3 bytes assuming int uses 4 bytes of data and if long uses 8 bytes,
I want to read 0 to 7 bytes as long's data and see what value it gives back.
    Can anyone help me with C# code.

Regards,
Vix

Comment: Your own process or another process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be very dangerous,  how are getting the address and how are you evaluating that it is valid?  Not every address will be valid and trying to read from some of them will result in exceptions.

But you can use the [Marshal.Read*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal_methods.aspx) methods do to this.

```
int intValue = Marshal.ReadInt32(addr);
long longValue = Marshal.ReadInt64(addr);
```

You will need to catch AccessViolationException's as well.

Also are you trying to read from a virtual address or from physical memory.  From C# you will only be reading from the [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your process.  You'd have to use a kernel mode driver to get direct access to the physical memory on your computer.

Comment: If you need to catch AccessViolations you probably did something wrong.

Comment: int i = 16;
long j = 56;
int* p1;
long* p2;
p2 = &j;
p1 = &i;

I want to read the value stored from 0 - 3 bytes of int as int is allocated with 4 bytes and long with 8 bytes
similary 0-7 bytes of long.

Comment: Why do you need pointers for that in the first place? The int already contains these bytes.

Comment: You can use `BitConverter.GetBytes` to get the bytes representing an int.

Comment: I want to retrieve value stored from 0 - 3 bytes in the integer.How do i do it? I was using pointers for another purpose.

Comment: @Vix - Either you want `BitConverter.GetBytes` as CodeInChaos is asking or we have no idea what are asking.